# How to communicate with a project on another server from a GWT project

Tags: http, sockets, gwt, udp, communication

I have a GWT project A and another project B on another computer. Now I want to call the business logic in project B whenever a user presses a button in project A. Project B cannot be a GWT project because of other restrictions.

How can I do that?

I tried to use sockets, but that is not possible with GWT: java.net.Socket is not supported by Google App Engine's Java runtime environment. If a uncheck the usage of GWT App Engine in the project properties, my application does not start anymore (java.lang.NoSuchMethodError's).

So what I need is a behaviour like the following:

1. Fire an event in project A
2. Notice that the event was fired and call method x

Comment: Apparently GAE has Channel API: http://code.google.com/intl/sl-SI/appengine/docs/java/channel/overview.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting notification from the client, about the event, you can use `HttpURLConnection` to contact the project B. Project B must have HTTP interface to handle the request from the A.

You can read more details about `HttpURLConnection` here: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/urlfetch/

Calling certain method on the B project is matter of good contract between the request parameters and the mechanism for calling methods(I guess some kind of mapping).

Comment: You will always need the mapping. I solved this problem like this: project A sends a message to project B via XMPP. The advantage is that the projects can also be deployed on different machines.